# Angular controller undefined within jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine

I'm currently having an issue writing some tests for a controller. Within the `beforeEach` block below I need to instantiate an activityController and inject the scope object. I have added a console log before the call to the $controller service and this is outputted however the one after never gets called therefore something is breaking within the `$controller` block.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    console.log(activityController);

    activityController = $controller('activityController', {
        '$scope': $scope
    });

    console.log("TEST");
}));
```

Within my tests I'm seeing `Type Error: activityController is undefined in C:\.......\activity.controller.test.js` so I know it's definitely not being instantiated.

[image]

I've created a gist of the relevant files here: https://gist.github.com/junderhill/e181ce866ab1ebb1f805

The activity controller not being instantiated correctly is causing my tests to fail. Any ideas on what may be causing this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Jason.

Try to set `activityService` whilst creating controller, because you should also inject all services.

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't seem to make any difference. The error message remained the same and the second `console.log` wasn't hit.

Comment: Maybe you’ve forgotten to set `currentTeam` in `beforeEach`?

Comment: I think I'm getting close to solving this. It seems that the request that goes to set the currentTeam hasn't returned in time for when I instantiate the controller therefore it's falling over. I need to mock the roleService as well I think as currently i'm using the real service.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line may be causing the problem:

```
    mockRoleService.setCurrentRole({"AssignmentID":21,"EndDate":"2049-12-31T00:00:00","StartDate":"2000-01-01T00:00:00","UserType":1,"AccessLevel":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Description":"Demonstration Territory 1","TeamID":null});
```

It looks like you're using an actual injected version of your roleService instead of a stubbed literal, so it's actually going to fire off your implementation, which is...

```
this.setCurrentRole = function(role){
currentRole = role;
$http.get("http://localhost:14938/api/User/GetTeamForAssignment?assignmentId=" + role["AssignmentID"] + "&assignmentType=" + role["UserType"])
.success(function (data) {
  currentTeam = data;
});
```

}

If you're going to use that service directly with an $httpBackend mock, I'd actually wrap that operation in a $q.defer(), because currently as that stands, that is an asychronous call.  You'll want that operation to complete to set the currentTeam properly.  So, maybe something like..

```
this.setCurrentRole = function(role){
var deferred = $q.defer();
currentRole = role;
$http.get("http://localhost:14938/api/User/GetTeamForAssignment?assignmentId=" + role["AssignmentID"] + "&assignmentType=" + role["UserType"])
.success(function (data) {
  currentTeam = data;
  deferred.resolve();
});
return deferred.promise;
```

}

And obviously do a deferred.reject of some sort if something wonky comes back from HTTP.

Hope that helps!

Eric